# How could I boot my Pixel 3 XL with the compiled android (version is 12.0, and branch name is crosshatch) AOSP kernel with KASAN and KCOV on?

Tags: kernel, pixel, android-source, address-sanitizer, fuzzing

I am here to seek for help as I have stuck in the problem for several weeks, and still have no idea how to deal with it.
As I meant to test the android kernel with KASAN and KCOV on with syzkaller tool, and I built the android 12.0 AOSP from source code, and flashed it to the Pixel 3XL device successfully; Next, I built the independent crosshatch kernel to flash it to the device and boot successfully, too; However, when I built the kernel source code with KASAN and KCOV on(CONFIG_KASAN=y, CONFIG_TEST_KASAN=y, CONFIG_KCOV, CONFIG_SLUB=y, CONFIG_SLUB_DEBUG=y, CONFIG_CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE=y, CONFIG_KASAN_INLINE=y), the android device stuck in the fastboot loader interface and cannot boot.

AS the KASAN user docs says, the KASAN config will enlarge the kernel size, so I compare the original(default successfully boot) android kernel size is 19.8M, and my kernel with KASAN on is 28.2M, is this the reason I cannot boot my Pixel 3XL successfully? How can I get rid of this boot failure error? Is it possible to resize the boot.img size capacity in Pixel 3XL?

I would greatly appreciate any of your help!